# Visual studio 2010 crashes when designing datasets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, strongly-typed-dataset

I am working on a project with approx 75 strongly typed datasets that was upgraded from VS 2008 (which was previously upgraded from VS 2005).  Visual studio crashes often while editing these datasets.

Has anyone else seen this issue?  Is there a workaround of any sort?

Comment: Haven't experienced this myself, but have heard of crash reports with VS 2010...  would highly recommend sending this as a bug to Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Delete every ".Designer.vb/cs" file and then right click on each xsd file and select "Run Custom Tool" to create a fresh on for VS2010.  I notice that clears up a many problems in VS2010 with datasets, especially upgraded datasets.